# How to get the new JNDI names (esp. ConnectionFactory)

Tags: jndi, jboss7.x

I upgraded to JBoss 7.0.1 and we are using the following JNDI lookup to get a connection to a HornetQ message queue.

```
InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext();
QueueConnectionFactory qf = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup( "ConnectionFactory" );
```

This results in a `NameNotFoundException` when used with JBoss 7. I have also tried the following:

- java:jms/ConnectionFactory
- java:env/ConnectionFactory

.. and some others. But I think guessing won't get me far. How do I get the new JNDI names that are not logged in the console (like my EJB beans)?

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

> java:jboss/ConnectionFactory

Did not test it, but would give that a try, since https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7 says:

> Unqualified relative names like "DefaultDS" or "jdbc/DefaultDS"
>    should be qualified relative to "java:comp/env", "java:module/env", or
>    "java:jboss/env", depending on the context.

Correction and edit: Had a look at my installation and correct is:

> java:/ConnectionFactory

as it is defined in domain.xml also.

Comment: Thanks, `java:/ConnectionFactory` is definitely correct, did not configure messaging in the standalone.xml, see my answer. Not sure, if the configuration in `standalone.xml` must be `ConnectionFactory` or `java:/ConnectionFactory` in JBoss 7.0.1 (see the bug tracker). Works now and will mark your answer as correct, since the JNDI name is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

The whole HornetQ part was deactivated by default in JBoss 7. Had to copy the corresponding part from the `standalone-preview.xml` to `standalone.xml` and move everything from `META-INF/hornetq-jms.xml` to the JBoss config.

Now I have the ConnectionFactory configured like this:

```
        <jms-connection-factories>
            <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                <connectors>
                    <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                </connectors>
                <entries>
                    <entry name="ConnectionFactory"/>
                </entries>
            </connection-factory>
        </jms-connection-factories>
```

and I can use it by doing this JNDI lookup:

```
QueueConnectionFactory qf = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup( "java:/ConnectionFactory" );
```

This is caused by a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1210) in the JMS configuration of JBoss 7. Seems to be fixed in 7.0.1, used that version, didn't notice any fix - however, the above configuration works.